# Codeigniter: POST not passing on local wamp server but works on hostgator

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp

I am doing a simple form which works with post or get, but, when I do a form using codeigniter is not able to do post. Just get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://postimg.org/image/cwyr380zp/

This is how I solved it. I just had to enable the mod_rewrite.

Comment: I did this plus I accessed localhost using 127.0.0.1